# Intellij: What's the difference between 'Run' and 'Run...'

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-13

[image: Run toolbar screenshot]

I'm trying to change the default Run keyboard shortcut to ⌘R. - Because I dont want to reach for the trackpad everytime and my fingers are not long enough to do ⌥⇧F10 at once. What's the difference between 'Run' and 'Run...'?

Comment: Did you try it before you asked?

Comment: @StephenC 'Run' was greyed out, I'm not sure why. I tried google too.

Comment: It was probably greyed out because you didn't have an entry point class as the "current" one; i.e. the current context was not "Run"-able.  It sounds like you might need to re-do the Intellij tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`...` is used in menus to indicate that it will lead to a dialog box.